# How to select values that happened right after a certain action in SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a SQL dataset like this:

```
UserID  Action       Time
111     open email   03/02/2019 12:00
111     open pageD   03/02/2019 12:12
222     sign in      02/04/2019 13:25
222     open email   02/04/2019 14:00
222     open pageA   02/04/2019 14:20
...
```

How to show a list with each person's id, and the action they took right after opening their email? I want to get a result like this:

```
UserID  PageOpenTime       Action
111     03/02/2019 12:12   open pageD
222     02/04/2019 14:20   open pageA
...
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What database is this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the action, use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(action) over (partition by userid order by time) as next_action
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'open email';
```

If you want the full row that follows the "open email" row, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(action) over (partition by userid order by time) as prev_action
      from t
     ) t
where prev_action = 'open email';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I found the first and the second command return the same result. I want to show the row follows the "open email" row. I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: @Stella . . . The version with `lag()` should show all the rows following `'open email'`.

Comment: @Stella SQL Fiddle of using [lead](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0557/2) and [lag](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0557/3) shows that this answer is right on point. You can modify the `select` clause of the `lag` version to get the [result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0557/6) you're asking for.